# Select either one of the row with condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have this sql table and rows defined in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea65/1)

In **SUPPLIER_DETAILS** table there is a field called **IS_PAYABLE** which will have values either null or 'Y'.

If `IS_PAYABLE='Y'`, there could be one or more records for each **PRODUCT_REG** with different **PRODUCT_NO**.
E.g. `PRODUCT_REG = 'HP_C20'` has two records with `IS_PAYABLE='Y'`.

```
HP_C20  FR-A    GB-A128     Y
HP_C20  FR-A    GB-A098     Y
```

What I would like to have is if `IS_PAYABLE='Y'` and if there are multiple records for one **PRODUCT_REG**, then I would want only either one of the record and I want all the records with `IS_PAYABLE is null`.

How can I achieve this? If I did not make my requirement understandable, I will explain further.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from 
   (select a.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by product_reg order by product_no) as rnk 
   from SUPPLIER_DETAILS a
   order by PRODUCT_REG)
where is_payable is null or rnk = 1;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea65/50)

In inner query I've ranked the products with the same product_reg.

In the outer query i've got only one product per product_reg(the first ranked) and all non payable products.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Thanks a lot, this worked like a charm. If I encounter any issue with records I will come back to you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM   supplier_details s 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT s1.* 
                  FROM   supplier_details s1 
                  WHERE  s.is_payable = 'Y' 
                         AND s1.is_payable = 'Y' 
                         AND s.product_reg = s1.product_reg 
                         AND s.product_no < s1.product_no) 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   supplier_details 
WHERE  is_payable IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25c52/2/0

*EDIT: below code should also work(union is redundant)*

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM   supplier_details s 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT s1.* 
                  FROM   supplier_details s1 
                  WHERE  s.is_payable = 'Y' 
                         AND s1.is_payable = 'Y' 
                         AND s.product_reg = s1.product_reg 
                         AND s.product_no < s1.product_no)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e69b/1/0

Answer (score 3):

In this situation `row_number()` analytical function is going to be in handy.

```
   select product_reg
        , product_supplier_code
        , product_no
        , is_payable
     from (select t.*
                , row_number() over (partition by product_reg order by product_no) m
             from SUPPLIER_DETAILS t
          )
    where m = 1
       or is_payable is null
    order by product_reg
```

[**Demo#1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea65/117)

**In addition**

Seems to be a duplicate. To distinguish the answer a little bit here is another approach you can use to get the desired result

```
select product_reg
    , max(PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_CODE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY product_reg) PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_CODE
    , max(PRODUCT_NO) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY product_reg) PRODUCT_NO
    , max(IS_PAYABLE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY product_reg) IS_PAYABLE
from SUPPLIER_DETAILS t
group by product_reg 
order by product_reg
```

[**Demo#2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea65/119)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this, but when returning the records `where IS_PAYABLE = 'Y'` use an aggregate to always return the `MAX()` or `MIN()` value

```
select PRODUCT_REG, PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_CODE, max(PRODUCT_NO) PRODUCT_NO, IS_PAYABLE
from SUPPLIER_DETAILS
where IS_PAYABLE = 'Y'
group by  PRODUCT_REG, PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_CODE, IS_PAYABLE
union all 
select PRODUCT_REG, PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_CODE, PRODUCT_NO, IS_PAYABLE
from SUPPLIER_DETAILS
where IS_PAYABLE is null
order by PRODUCT_REG
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea65/116)